# I'd like to count the documents with the matching "name" property AND group them by "name" at the same time

Tags: node.js, mongoose, group-by

Let's say I have a `User` collection:

```
schema = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  ...
  ...
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

I would like to write a mongoose query that would count how many users go by the name Mike, Andy, Jerry... In other words, I would like to GROUP them BY the same name and count all the groups.
So far, the only idea I've come up with is to do the simplest `find()` and `select("username")` and `lean()` and then filter the result in the `exec()` function using lodash or underscore.

But I'd like to know if it's possible to get this result using only mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want mongodb to handle the query internally you could use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

In mongodb it looks like:

```
db.users.aggregate(
  [{
    $group: {
      _id: '$firstName', // similar to SQL group by, a field value for '_id' will be returned with the firstName values
      count: {$sum: 1} // creates a field value 'count' that will store the value
    }
  }]
);
```

Which in mongoose using the [aggregate pipeline](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) would be:

```
Users.aggregate()
  .group({ _id: '$firstName', count: { $sum: 1 }})
  .exec(function (err, res) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(res);
});
```

You could use a projection to modify the field name for `_id` to be `firstName` if desired.

Comment: This answer is a bit more detailed than Johnny's so I'll go with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) with a [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline stage to do this:

```
User.aggregate(
    {$group: {_id: '$firstName', count: {$sum: 1}}},
    function(err, result) {...}
);
```